# Suppose I want to search a type of file in a folder.how can I search that in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Suppose I have a parent folder which contains some more folders. I want to search the files which are present in the sub folders but I have the information of only parent folder (i.e. I know the path of parent folder). I want to list all files of same type present in sub folders. How can I list them all or search the required file type in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the search string in the project navigator and manually refine from those results. Xcode's project navigator does not distinguish depth for you. If the items do not exist, you can add a folder reference ;)

Comment: Yes, the wink-icon means that there are a lot of 'Xcode' questions which really have nothing to do with Xcode - this looks like another one of them. If I'm wrong, then you have an answer which relates to Xcode. Otherwise: Xcode is an IDE. It is used for multiple platforms, multiple languages, and with many libraries. It would make a lot more sense to tag and word questions appropriately, and more specifically. With the current description, I could provide you with a handful of solutions, most of which you are likely not interested in.